# Create 2D array from where clause on 1D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array containing integer values:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,3])
a
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3])
```

I would like to create a 2D array with the first dimension holding the index of the integer value in the 1D array:

```
idx = [np.where(a == (i+1)) for i in range(a.max())]
```

But this returns a list (duh):

```
type(idx)
list
```

And the first dimension is a series of tuples:

```
type(idx[0])
tuple
```

How can I return a 2D numpy array of indices of values from a 1D array using a where clause?

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
array([[0],[1,4,5,7],[2,3,6,8]])
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but if you want `idx` as a 2D array, it won't be done since `idx` does not have a regular shape.

Comment: You need to clarify this question. You specify the first dimension of the 2D array, but not the second. Can you give an example of the kind of output you are looking for.

Comment: I added expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can come to a 2D-array would be:

```
In [147]: np.array(tuple(np.where(a == e)[0] for e in np.unique(a)))
Out[147]: 
array([array([ 0, 14, 15, 16]),
       array([ 1,  4,  5,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21]),
       array([ 2,  3,  6,  8, 12, 18, 20])], dtype=object)
```

But it is a 1D array or arrays.

Part of your issue is that `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays so that it will have the same interface no matter how many dimensions your array has. Since yours only have one you can get the 0-index.

Then I would suggestion using `np.unique` since it is sort of nicer but it would skip indices not present in `a`. So if that is dead important, then just change back but use `range(a.max() + 1)`:

```
In [149]: np.array(tuple(np.where(a == e)[0] for e in range(a.max() + 1)))
Out[149]: 
array([array([], dtype=int64), array([ 0, 14, 15, 16]),
       array([ 1,  4,  5,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21]),
       array([ 2,  3,  6,  8, 12, 18, 20])], dtype=object)
```

Because indices start at 0 not 1.